# Pass variable to STEP 0 in BI customer exit

Tags: abap, sap-bw

How can I pass values from variable used in report to step 0? As of now I can get variable value in other steps than zero. 
I've checked table i_t_var_range and it is just empty.

So is it possible to get variable value in step 0?

Comment: You can create variables with DATA or using inline declaration, then assign these variables some values and use it in your loop boundaries

Comment: Does it apply to variables used in report? When user fill in this variable on prompt?

Comment: What is step 0?

Comment: @Suncatcher please follow that [link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/1d/ca10d858c2e949ba4a152c44f8128a/frameset.htm)
**I_STEP = 0
The enhancement is not called from the Variables screen. The call can originate from the authorization check or from the monitor.**